# What is a correct naming convention for Java method returning collection of elements?

Tags: java, methods, collections, naming-conventions, naming

I have a class `Person` and a method returning `Collection<Person>`. Is there a naming convention for this in Java? Should I name it `findPersons` or rather `findPeople`? Which version is preferable when we have name with irregular plural name in English?

Comment: Note that both forms are acceptable in English: "people" is more colloquial, but "persons" appears in the traditional wording of English marriage vows: "I call upon all persons here present..."; Or in reporting of a crime "perpetrated by person or persons unknown".

Answer (score 2):

Name it what it ***does by code***.

```
findPersons // since it would find a collection of Person
```

As long as it's readable and makes sense to relate to the existing code, its good.

Comment: Will you do the same with `Child`? `findChilds`? Or rather `findChildren`?

Comment: @PiotrPradzynski same there as well, if you want to be grammar correct there, you can think of renaming to `findCollectionOfChild`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it straightforward AT ALL TIMES. I'm tending towards a more 'functional' approach regarding this to avoid it all :) I'd use just "**find()**", and perhaps not as part of this class but more as a generic function as it makes it more bulky and less re-usable. Something in the lines of this: "Collection find(args...)"

The result collection itself is revealing enough zero or more is to be expected. (or the Optional if zero or one is to be expected)
I mean, it is Object-oriented programming, but not Objects-oriented programming ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the name and function of the class.

If the class' function is to manage a collection of `Person` objects (e.g., `PersonManager` or `PersonList`), then the method should just be called `find`, because the return type is implied.

Otherwise, I would follow [@nullpointer's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315723/what-is-a-correct-naming-convention-for-java-method-returning-collection-of-elem/46315823#46315823) by naming the method `findPersons`, as it explains what the code is doing.